# Is there such a thing as a fully differential line driver?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, components, differential, balanced

I'm looking to find something similar to the TI drv134 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv134.pdf), but then with differential inputs instead of single ended.

Is there even such a thing? I can't seem to find it.
I can of course easily place an opamp before the drv134's input but i'd rather have one less component.

Comment: What sort of signal are you sending? (analog/digital, voltage levels? type of "line" being driven? etc.)

Comment: It's audio, coming from a CS4272 codec. Each of the differential outputs (Vout+, Vout-) has voltage swing of 2.5vpp and is centered around 2.5v. The "line" being driven is either a balanced TRS plug or a unbalanced TS one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer: the THAT1606.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use a differential opamp with differential outputs like [OPA1632](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1632.pdf). Other manufacturers offer similar products.

Comment: I believe those are fully differential amplifiers. The difference with the drv134 is that the latter contains a cross-coupling scheme, making it possible to drive a single ended load without consuming to much power because of shorting out one of the outputs to ground. This is especially nice if the output is a TRS jack and the type of plug (TS / TRS) is unknown.

Comment: All audio gear which has balanced IO connectors uses single ended signaling inside, because it is simple and it works. Chip manufacturers design chips for this market... what you want is different from what this market wants... economics are against you...

Comment: The codec i’m using has both differential inputs and outputs. Since it runs on “only” 5v this helps the signal to noise ratio. Someone on another forum suggested me the THAT1646, which isn’t cheap indeed. Might be worth it though.

Comment: THAT1646 looks good. Expensive. Economics are against you... but if you make money selling your product, then this is no problem.